# What problem in combinatorics-on-words could this be a formula for: $\frac{2^i i}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

This came from a problem that I *have* solved, but it got me thinking.

Below is the original question I had to answer (as was translated to English by me just now):

> *G* is a simple graph on 32 vertices, defined as follows:
>
> A vertex in *G* is a 5-part-long string consisting of the letters *a,b*.
>
> For example, the string *aabab* is a vertex in *G*. Likewise, *aaaaa* is a
>   vertex in *G*.
>
> Any two vertices *x,y* are connected by an edge if and only if the
>   strings (vertrices) *x,y* coincide (are identical) in each of the five
>   letters (parts/elements) of the string **except one element.**
>
> For example, there is an edge between the vertex *aabab* to the vertex
>   *abbab*, because these strings differ from each other only in one place
>   (the second letter in the string).
>
> What is the number of edges in *G*?

So I figured out that the answer is $80 = \frac{2^i i}{2}$ , where *i* is the length of the string, i.e. $\frac{2^5 \cdot 5}{2}$. If the string was 7-part-long, for example, the answer would be $448 = \frac{2^7 \cdot 7}{2}$.

But what if the strings had to differ in *two* places instead of one? I'm unsure what formula I would use *then*. Does this type of combinatorial problem have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any simple graph, the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges.

If the strings have length $n$, and if an edge is defined as a mismatch at exactly $k$ positions, then each string has degree $\binom{n}{k}$.

Since there are $2^n$ strings, the sum of the degrees is $\binom{n}{k}2^n$,
hence the number of edges is $\binom{n}{k}2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Uh-huh, so what you do is just put it all together like that. Now I see why $\frac{2^i i}{2}$ worked. If $n=k=i$, then $\binom{n}{k}2^{n−1}=n2^{n−1}=\frac{n2^n}{2}=\frac{2^i i}{2}$.

Comment: So the only aspects of combinatorics you had to rely on were the multiplication principle and a k-combination.

Comment: @Megabyte216: Yes, that together with the key result that for any simple graph, the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges.

Comment: Oh, and a permutation with repetition, but I suppose it itself could be regarded as an application of the multiplication principle. Nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It helps to think in terms of binary vectors and bitwise modulo 2 addition (XOR).
Map $a\rightarrow 0,b\rightarrow 1,$ say. Let $n$ be the length.

Consider all vectors of Hamming weight $k$ (with exactly $k$ 1's). There are $\binom{n}{k}$ such vectors. Let $$V_n=\{0,1\}^n.$$

Let $a$ be any word of weight $k$. Note that as $u$ ranges over $V_n,$ the pair $(u,u+a)$ ranges over the ordered pair of words that are exactly apart by the word $a$.

We want the unordered pair, so the answer is $\binom{n}{k} 2^{n-1},$ since $|V_n|=2^n.$

Comment: Now that's a cool alternative way to approach the problem. Gives it more of a perspective on how it's applicable in programming and computer science.